# Oracle - Select a value in to a variable and use it in next select statement

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi Every one I am trying to Select a value in to a variable and use it in next select statement but it is not working can anyone help me plz... is it possible to do so?

I am using oracle 10.5 with Toad

```
variable  v_NextID int;
begin
begin
  SELECT NOTE_ID INTO  v_NextID FROM  (
      SELECT NOTE_ID,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY NOTE_ID ASC ) AS row_num
       FROM tableName WHERE ID ='838'
       ) t
     WHERE row_num = 2;

end;

       select v_NextID, ID from tableName  WHERE ID ='838';
end
```

Comment: int is not a datatype in oracle. User Integer or Number. Also post the error you get so that we can try and advise more accurately.

Comment: I have even tried number -  Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
  v_NextID number;

begin
  SELECT NOTE_ID INTO  v_NextID FROM  (
      SELECT NOTE_ID,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY NOTE_ID ASC ) AS row_num
       FROM tableName WHERE ID ='838'
       ) t
     WHERE row_num = 2;

     select v_NextID, ID 
       into ... -- here you need to add INTO clause
     from tableName  WHERE ID ='838';
end;
```